# Open Links in Default Browser (instead of In-app Browser) for Wikitude Studio Offline App

Tags: ios, wikitude

I'm using Wikitude Studio, and I have exported my project as an Offline App. On my project, I have several buttons that when tapped, it would open the links with the in-app browser. The in-app browser isn't the best as it limits downloading a file. I need help with the following:

1. How do I allow the in-app browser to download the file? Specifically, a .vcf
2. How do I make the buttons open the links in the default browser (say, Safari or Chrome) instead of the in-app broswer?

Any guidance will be very helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can force the Wikitude SDK to use the default browser by modifying the downloaded Wikitude Studio project.
To do this, follow these steps:
* Open converter.js
* search for 'openInBrowser'. You will see that this function is only called with one parameter, the url to open
* add a second bool parameter, 'true'. This forces the default OS browser to open instead of the in-app browser.